# Tomcat Apache Web Server still using ciphers with medium strength (<112 bits) even while configuring ciphers in connector

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

We have configured SSL in Apache Tomcat 6.0.20 at 8443 port#.

We have tenable Nessus tool which scans for vulnerabilities. It reported the web server has a "Medium Strength ciphers supported".

We went through Tomcat Documentation. We can configure the list of ciphers in ciphers attribute in connector element.

We configured from IBMJSSE2 Security Provider as the cipher list

For ex: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

But, still the same vulnerability is getting listed and the above cipher is not getting selected in "Server Hello" SSL message. Instead it is selecting a medium level cipher "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" only.

Do we know why this behavior?

Some Extra details:

Tomcat Version: 6.0.20
Java version: J2RE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc-32 jvmap3260sr4ifx-20090409_33254

IBM documentation of List of JSSE ciphers supported in Java6

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.60.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/ciphersuites.html

Apache Tomcat 6.0 Documentation on how to configure SSL
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

server.xml ssl settings

```
<Connector port="8443" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" ciphers="TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHS_RSA_WITH_A‌​ES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_R‌​SA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC‌​_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_WIT‌​H_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" >

New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID: 58B59B0B19255900580A16786D9F040BE19D236A6C16B1A53C281E6DDE072BDF
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: F037145E80507808391326B77F3A175015FAD3C356FDD350ADC8FA69FCB7CEDC0443F3AF10BDA71544806F010D1B3A7C
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1488296715
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

Comment: please share your server.xml snippet. You'll probably need to disable the weaker ciphers which are part of ssl2.0

Comment: @monish

Please find requested connector details

`
<Connector port="8443" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100"  maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" ciphers="TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" >
`
We are already disabled the weaker ciphers by using only the ciphers in the list. But, this list has the medium strength cipher lists

Comment: Sorry for the improper pasting. Unable to change the xml as code block.

Comment: SSLHonorCipherOrder can be used to instruct connecting client to use the high secure cipher that is first available from the list of ciphers that is received for connecting. use nmap ssl-enum-ciphers script to check if the required cipher is supported by server

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the tomcat SSL settings to update the sslProtocol to TLS from SSL (default)

for tomcat versions < 6.0.38

```
sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

for tomcat versions  >= 6.0.38

```
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

Read more [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-disable-weak-ciphers-and-ssl-2-in-tomcat.html)

Additional Step :

Download and update JCE policy jars in your JVM, since tomcat refers to JCE for cipher suites

Comment: Even with the changes, It is still taking the weaker cipher

    New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1488296715
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)

Comment: @SashiDharan can you update your question with the latest server.xml. It seems even though you have disabled lower versions of SSL, one or more of the ciphers you have explicitly specified is weak. Note that different ciphers suites may be considered weak/strong in different TLS versions

Comment: To know the combination of TLS version + Cipher suites that you should specify, you can refer this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Cipher

Comment: @SashiDharan note that in an attempt to be more secure, you dont end up being too restrictive in terms of what cipher suites your web server can offer. There is no point being secure if no-one can connect. I'd suggest knowing the available cipher suites to your JVM version from here https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html, then add all of them, then hit the Nessus Tool and remove 1-1 for which you get the warning